# How to get table data without mention columns name in row_to_json

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, postgis

The below script is perfect for specified columns, I got results what I expected. but I would like to get all columns from table.Thank you for helping.

```
SELECT row_to_json(fc) FROM (
 SELECT 'FeatureCollection' As type, array_to_json(array_agg(f)) As features FROM(
  SELECT 'Feature' As type, ST_AsGeoJSON(lg.geom)::json As geometry,
      row_to_json((id, name)) As properties FROM coffee_shops As lg
    ) As f
) As fc
```

Comment: Hey there. Could you also add the table structure, some data sample and the exact expected result?

Comment: "type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"id":1,"name":"1369 Coffee House","address":"1369 Cambridge St","city":"Cambridge","state":"MA","zip":"02139"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-71.10044,42.373695]}} expected results

Comment: Please Add you table structure for exact quary

Answer (score 0):

To include ALL fields (including the geometry), you would pass the table name or alias to `row_to_json`

```sql
select 
row_to_json(lg) As properties FROM coffee_shops As lg
```

Comment: but geom filed can't convert in geojson

Comment: If you put **all** fields in the json, it must include the geometry and this code will properly convert it. Some readers will work just fine with it. It is up to you do decide if you want to exclude some fields or not... but your question specifies you wanted all fields

Comment: sorry for that what I mention,   "type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"id":1,"name":"1369 Coffee House","address":"1369 Cambridge St","city":"Cambridge","state":"MA","zip":"02139"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-71.10044,42.373695]}} expected results